# Tools/Existing Implementations similar to what Google is using

Tags: php, libraries

I was wondering if there was a tool for parsing comments\reviews and categorizing them by a synonym and searching\ordering the comments\reviews by the number of times they match the synonym?

Like the What people are saying [section](http://maps.google.com/maps/place?oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&q=cebu+hotel&fb=1&gl=ph&hq=hotel&hnear=Cebu+City&cid=14548290030465956601).

EDIT: another sample [link](http://atlanta.citysearch.com/profile/2999083/atlanta_ga/georgian_terrace_hotel.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Solr does this with the [mlt (more like this) parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis).

Comment: sorry for the delay, i was hoping to get more options, I ended up using a simple Naive Bayes implementation